# Output array in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to get result of a table "empDetails" using simple stored proc in Oracle SQL developer. Below is the SP definition

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE TEST_ALL (all_Cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) AS 
BEGIN
open all_Cursor for
    select * from empDetails;
END TEST_ALL;
```

when I execute the stored proc, I cannot able to view the output in Output result tab. 
But I can fetch the data through direct SQL query `select * from empDetails;`

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this way:

```
 declare
        a  SYS_REFCURSOR;

        v_emp_detls  empDetails%rowtype;

        begin

         TEST_ALL (all_Cursor=>a );

          loop
            FETCH a INTO v_emp_detls;
                EXIT WHEN a%NOTFOUND;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_emp_detls.col1||v_emp_detls.col2..and so on);

          end loop;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the following:

```
VARIABLE rc REFCURSOR;

begin
  test_all(:rc);
end;
/

PRINT rc;
```

which works in SQL*Plus and in most other GUIs that allow you to run the above as a script (e.g. SQL Developer, Toad, etc)